# How to pass decoded message to next handler?

Tags: java, netty

The first `ChannelHandler` of my pipeline is a class that inherits from `SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler`. I've overrided the `messageReceived()` method that now decodes the incoming message (a SIP request) using JAIN SIP. The next `ChannelHandler` I have is a validator for the SIP request. But, in this handler I want to work with the POJO, not with the `ChannelBuffer`.

How to pass the decoded POJO to the next handler?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should better extend OneToOneDecoder as it makes it easier to handle.

If you need more complex solution (like you get a frame and want to generate more then one pojo out of it you can use "Channels.fireMessageReceived(...)" to hand it to the next handler in the ChannelPipeline